# window.location vs window.Location

Tags: javascript, window.location, window-object

What is the difference between **window.location** and **window.Location** in Javascript.
The first one is object but the second one is a function,
I know the use of the first one, but what is the use of second one?

Comment: `window.location instanceof Location`

Comment: In other words, `window.Location` is a constructor function, and `window.location` is an object that was created by that constructor function

Comment: everything defined in the global scope is implicitly a property of the window object. the function Location is the constructor function for the location property itself.

Comment: Even better (works in Edge at least): `window.location instanceof window.Location`